# Mutagen All File Types

Tags: python, mutagen

I was given a task to change a function that reads all MP3 files to reading any type of files Mutagen is able to read. Am I suppose to do it by hand? (I.E if .endswith = this or that), or is there a generic way of achieving this?

This is the way the loop looks like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower().endswith(".mp3"):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Comment: Do you know all of them?

Comment: No, I only know of .mp3 .ogg, .apev2 and .wma

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
supported = ['.mp3','.ogg','.wma'] #put all known here

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower() in supported: #test if filename ext is in supported
            fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Comment: So there is no generic way of not having to specify the type?

Comment: I don't know mutagen, but unless the API itself doesn't have a function that returns all supported extensions there isn't.